# Definition of Distance in Peak coding challenge

Tags: algorithm

In the following question I am struggling to understand one part of the problem explanation.

https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/10-prime_and_composite_numbers/flags/

It states that for K flags the distance between any two flags should be greater than equal to K. It then states that the distance between indices P and Q is equal to |P-Q|.
According to this definition, then in the two flag example K=2, peak three should be included as |3-1|=K=2.
However in the example peak 3 is not included.

Can someone please explain?

Comment: That is one of the way. We can take {1, 3} or {1, 5}, {1, 10} and some more.

Comment: If the maximum distance is K=2, distance is defined as the absolute difference between the indices, how can {1, 3} be included? |3-1|=2? Can you please clarify?

Comment: The example in the link says that for K=2 only {1, 5} and {1,10} are valid.

Comment: Yes, The absolute difference between indices should be greater or equal to k.

Comment: OK so K=2 but so does |3-1|? Thus the distance is equal to K? Yet it is not included, in the example. I suppose their could be an error in the working and it should read distance > K? This would fit with the examples given.

Comment: {1, 3} is also a valid assignment.

Comment: OK but if that is the case {3,5} is also valid as it is the same distance as {1,3} and therefore peak 3 should be valid. But for K=2 peak 3 is not shown as being valid in the example in the link above?

Comment: There are several answers as I have already told in the first comment.